# Testing iPhone app on older OS versions in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode, version, simulator

All,
Is there a way to download older versions of the iPhone simulator to test an application with an older version of the iPhone OS? I'm running Xcode 3.2.2. and it only has iPhone OS 3.1.3 and I need to test on 3.1.2.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure this is nessessary? Since iOS 4 is free to everyone, and past triends show that iDevice users are pretty up to date, Testing on 4.0 and 3.1.3 should be good. Why do you feel the need to test 3.1.2 specifically? I don't know of an Apple site to download older versions, but I typically keep copies of every SDK and OS firmware release so when I get home I could probably dig up that SDK.

Comment: Did you tried to change the Deploymet Target ? it's not the same ?

Comment: @Cesar he wants to run 3.1.2 on the simulator, currently the sim only runs the latest 3.x os which is 3.1.2, and 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Head to

http://connect.apple.com

Click "Developer Tools" on the right

You can get all the way back to Xcode 1.0 if you like

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to do the same thing. The answer seems to be rather unsatisfying: You cannot use the simulator to test if your app runs on a previous iOS version. It only works on the device, according to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross%5Fdevelopment/Configuring/configuring.html):

> **iPhone OS Note:** Mac OS X v10.6 does
>   not support using iPhone Simulator
>   SDKs prior to version 3.0. In
>   addition, when building with the
>   simulator SDKs, the binary runs only
>   on the same OS version as the SDK, not
>   on earlier or later versions.

This seems really dull. How am I supposed to test backwards compatibility without having one physical iPhone for each SDK version? Not good.